# CSS Horizontally align text over image

Tags: html, css

I don't know if it is possible, but is it possible for a `<span>` of variable text length to be horizontally aligned over an image? The one catch with this, is I'd like the `<span>` to have a background color and the background color block should overlap the image.

I've tried setting the `<span>` to `display:inline-block` but it doesn't seem to end up horizontally aligned. Here is the code if you don't want to look in the fiddle (the HTML here should remain the same if-at-all-possible)

**The Code (https://jsfiddle.net/6c9gmvom/1/):**

```css
#wrapper {
  width:100%;
}
.txt {
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:40px; /* ideally I would not want to use a fixed width here */
  background-color:#ffffff;
} 
img {
  height:30px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="http://seedmagazine.com/slideshow/the_long_shot/img/8_the_long_shot_ss.jpg">
  <div id="modulewrapper">
    <span class="txt">hey</span>
    <div id="module"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the image as a background image... then set the span to display block.....

```css
#wrapper {
  width:100%;
}
.txt {
  text-align:center;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
} /* ideally I would not want to use a fixed width here */
img {
  height:30px;
  width:100%;
}

#modulewrapper { 
  padding: 200px 0;
background: url(http://seedmagazine.com/slideshow/the_long_shot/img/8_the_long_shot_ss.jpg) no-repeat center center; }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="modulewrapper">
    <span class="txt">hey</span>
    <div id="module"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm trying to get "hey" to overlap the image, as in "hey" will sit over the image

Comment: @Zac answer updated ... unless there's some reason a background image is unacceptable.

Comment: Many thanks again, it is the effect of @xxxmatko's answer that I'm looking for. I actually kept on reproducing what your snippit shows (I didn't want the background to stretch across the whole image)

Answer (score 1):

You can align it with css. I've updated your fiddle, check it out to see the result https://jsfiddle.net/6c9gmvom/8/

The css I've added is:

```
#wrapper {
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
}
#modulewrapper {
  text-align:center;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: Can this solution work if the .txt class does not have a fixed width?

Comment: Yes, you can see it in the fiddle. The width of the `.txt` is the width of the text inside it. It is displayed as inline block, and align in the center within the parent `#modulewrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure I understand what it is you are asking.
If im not mistaken what you want is for the text to be on top of the image.
This can be done as seen https://jsfiddle.net/6c9gmvom/9/

```
 #wrapper {width:100%;position:relative}
.txt {
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:40px;
  background-color:#ffffff; 
  z-index: 100;
  width:100%;
}
img {
height:30px;width:100%;
}

.imageClass{
  position:absolute;
   left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.txt {
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 15px;
}
img {
  height:30px;
  width:100%;
  position: relatable;
}
```